# I need to change the transparency of the object through the slider

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have this script to change the transparency of the object, which is initially turned off, and when I click on the button that turns it on, its clone appears ... but when I turn on this object, I cannot change the transparency ... There are no errors in the unity, just not transparency changes ...

```
     public class ChangeOpacity : MonoBehaviour
       {
        public GameObject currentGameObject;
        private AsistantControll AsistantControllScript;
        public float alpha = 0.5f;//half transparency
                  //Get current material
     private Material currentMat;

     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
      {
         AsistantControllScript = FindObjectOfType<AsistantControll>();

       currentMat = currentGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

    }

      // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
      {

       }



        void ChangeAlpha(Material mat, float alphaVal)
     {
     Color oldColor = mat.color;
     Color newColor = new Color(oldColor.r, oldColor.g, oldColor.b, alphaVal);
    mat.SetColor("_Color", newColor);


     }

      public void ChangeAlphaOnValue(Slider slider)
     {
 ChangeAlpha(currentMat, slider.value);
 }




 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things are wrong in your code, or you haven't wrote all your code.
From where your ChangeAlphaValue method is called ? What slider is passed in parameter to it ?
You should add a serialize field of your slider in your script and reference it in the Inspector.

```cs
[SerializeField] private Slider m_slider = null;

void Start()
{
    ...
    m_slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(ChangeAlphaOnValue);
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    m_slider.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(ChangeAlphaOnValue);
}

public void ChangeAlphaOnValue(float value)
{
    ChangeAlpha(currentMat, value);
}
```

With that code, your ChangeAlphaOnValue is called whenever your slider change value (when you drag it at runtime or set it by code).

Comment: Thank you for answer! when I press the button responsible for the inclusion of an object, its clone appears, while the original remains inactive, but if you make it active (in the project itself, during testing, click on the checkmark next to the object), then change its transparency using this script you can, but the transparency of the clone of this object cannot be changed ...

Comment: @AgniKai1_ What do you want to achieve exactly ? Do you want to change the opacity of all the clones ? 
If yes, the currentMat should take the sharedMaterial in your Start.
If not, you should update your currentMat reference by getting the material of your clone after you instantiated it.

Comment: thanks for your willingness to help! problem solved